# Class to protocol conversation in swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

I have this heavy basicVC Class subclass of UIViewController that I am trying to convert as vcprotocol.

It's the basicVC that is doing all work like god class. Which I would like to break into as vcProtocol.

I am trying to do is a separation of concern. Not all of the ViewControllers need to show the Alert View or Network not connected msg.

For example, I have indicatorView that I create in protocol extension as computed property. No error warning but no indicator is being shown. When I try to debug and do `po acticvityIndicator` I get the following error, which indicates that activityIndicator was never allocated.

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5a1012de027).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Code snippet:

```
protocol vcProtocol {
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView { get }
}
```

protocol extension:

```
extension vcProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray)
        indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        indicator.style = .whiteLarge
        indicator.color = .red
        indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return indicator
    }

    func showLoadingIndicator() {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    }

    func hideLoadingIndicator() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

I am not able to wrap my head around how to solve this. as I can only have computed properties in the protocol.
so I have them as get only properties.
my plan is to use the protocol extension to provide a default implementation.

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure if related but, do you add this `activityIndicator` as `subView` at any point?

Comment: You have your activity indicator view as a computed property, so every time you reference it, you’re going to get a new one!

Comment: @rob I am not getting it. Hence the error. At least that’s my assumption

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `po` doesn't mean the property is `nil`, It happens in case of properties defined in protocol extension, you can add a breakpoint in extension and validate it. You should add the code where you're using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `activityIndicator` is a computed property, so every time you reference the computed property, that `get` block will be called. The net effect is that, as written, each time you reference `activityIndicator`, you’re going to get a new instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView`, which is obviously not your intent.

Consider your `showLoadingIndicator`:

```
func showLoadingIndicator() {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
}
```

The first line (with `startAnimating`) will return a new `UIActivityIndicatorView` and the second line (with `isHidden`) will return yet another. And neither of these will be the same one that you presumably added to your subview.

This `activityIndicator` really should be instantiated once and only once. Unfortunately, you can’t define the stored property in an extension, so there are a few approaches:

1. You can let the `UIViewController` declare the stored property and just define methods method to configure, show, and hide it:

   ```
   protocol LoadingIndicatorProtocol: class {
       var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? { get set }
   }

   extension LoadingIndicatorProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

       func addLoadingIndicator() {
           let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
           indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
           indicator.style = .whiteLarge
           indicator.color = .red
           indicator.backgroundColor = .gray
           indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

           view.addSubview(indicator)
           // you might want to add the constraints here, too

           loadingActivityIndicator = indicator
       }

       func showLoadingIndicator() {
           loadingActivityIndicator?.startAnimating()
           loadingActivityIndicator?.isHidden = false
       }

       func hideLoadingIndicator() {
           loadingActivityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
           loadingActivityIndicator?.isHidden = true
       }
   }
   ```

   And then a `UIViewController` subclass simply has to define its own ivar for the `activityIndicator`, e.g.

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, LoadingIndicatorProtocol {
       var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?

       override viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           addLoadingIndicator()
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. The other approach is to use [associated objects](https://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) via [`objc_getAssociatedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418865-objc_getassociatedobject) and [`objc_setAssociatedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418509-objc_setassociatedobject), to achieve stored property behavior:

   ```
   protocol LoadingIndicatorProtocol {
       var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView { get }
   }

   private var associatedObjectKey = 0

   extension LoadingIndicatorProtocol {

       var loadingActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView {
           if let indicatorView = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &associatedObjectKey) as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
               return indicatorView
           }

           let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
           indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
           indicator.style = .whiteLarge
           indicator.color = .red
           indicator.backgroundColor = .gray
           indicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &associatedObjectKey, indicator, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

           return indicator
       }

       func showLoadingIndicator() {
           loadingActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
           loadingActivityIndicator.isHidden = false
       }

       func hideLoadingIndicator() {
           loadingActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
           loadingActivityIndicator.isHidden = true
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I like your first approach as I would like things swifty way. The swift compiler is complaining. about loadingActivityIndicator = indicator 
automatic fix to making addLoadingIndicator as mutating.  but then I am having an issue calling this method in my viewControllers. Thoughts?

Comment: @Alix - Did you define your protocol with the `class` qualifier?

Comment: You are right. I totally missed that one. thanks for pointing out.